How to reconcile Matt 12:25-26 to Ezekiel 30:10-11
In Matthew when Jesus and Satan interacted, in one of the temptations given by Satan we get the sense that he has authority over all nations :

Again, the devil took him to a very high mountain and showed him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory. And he said to him, “All these I will give you, if you will fall down and worship me.”
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭4‬:‭8‬-‭9‬ ‭ESV‬

However, it is mentioned in the Old Testament that wars and conflicts do exist between nations, such as Babylon coming to destroy Egypt.

Thus says the Lord God: “I will put an end to the wealth of Egypt, by the hand of Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon. He and his people with him, the most ruthless of nations, shall be brought in to destroy the land, and they shall draw their swords against Egypt and fill the land with the slain.”
‭‭Ezekiel‬ ‭30‬:‭10‬-‭11‬ ‭ESV‬‬

But later in Matthew, Jesus uses the argument that Satan's kingdom can’t be divided.

“Knowing their thoughts,” he said to them, “Every kingdom divided against itself is laid waste, and no city or house divided against itself will stand. And if Satan casts out Satan, he is divided against himself. How then will his kingdom stand?”
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭12‬:‭25‬-‭26‬ ‭ESV‬‬

My question is: given that Satan has/had authority over the nations in the past as well as these satanic nations then conquering one another as shown in Ezekiel, how does Jesus’s argument hold up that Satan's kingdom can’t be divided? Is he speaking only spiritually or something else?

Maybe "2 Kings 19:25 King James Version (KJV)" is useful.

Probably Satan was lying to Jesus, see John 8:44. Thus, I think the premise of your question is wrong. We cannot say that Satan ruled over any nation.
Also, from 2 Kings 19:25 we can learn that YHWH is the actual ruler over some nations (Assyria in this case).

@David I'd strongly disagree that Satan was lying. Jesus is omniscient. For the temptation to be real, the offer has to be real. Claiming "Satan was lying" undercuts Hebrews 4:15. On the other hand Satan has real power in this world (see John 16:11, 2 Cor. 4:4). Yes, it does belong to God and God still has ultimate power, but it's now in rebellion against God under the power of Satan. Satan could have ended that rebellion. This story becomes much more meaningful when you realize that Satan wasn't lying.

@user111403 thank you for the references.
I think your quotations do not justify the point "Satan wasn't lying" and also I don't think that the fact the S guy was lying diminishes the importance. I will justify these points in a reply to the OP's question later today (I hope).

Just this morning I read this explanation about Satan's empire, based on that Matthew text. This lengthy quote from the book really does clarify what's going on with the issues raised.

"It appears from this text, "If Satan also be divided against himself,
how shall his kingdom stand?" that the devils have a chief over them,
Satan, and that the other devils are his princes... And we read of
principalities and powers among the devils, which Christ spoiled by
his death, and triumphed over them upon the cross.
There is not one hint dropped in the scriptures that the devils ever
fall out or disagree; for, as there is no door of hope opened to them,
nor any ground to expect any favour from God, there is no place for
repenting or relenting; their mind is hardened and shut up under the
guilt of the unpardonable sin, and a continual sense of God's wrath,
and this fills them with eternal hatred both to God and man.
Their abode is principally in the air: Ephesians 2:2, "Wherein in time
past ye walked according to the course of this world, according to the
prince of the power of the air, the spirit that now worketh in the
children of disobedience." Their palaces are the hearts of poor
sinners... Many are the ways and means by which
the devil contrives to keep his possessions; and wonderfully hath he
fortified himself in the hearts of the children of men... The bulwarks
of Satan, by which he keeps possession of his strong holds are: The
select Works of the late Rev. William Huntington, Vol. IV, p.363,
Collingridge City Press London, 1856

Then Huntington lists (1) 'Darkness and blindness of mind' - 2 Corinthians 4:3-4, Revelation 18:2. Hatred to the light and a love to darkness keeps Satan on the throne of the sinner's affections - John 1:4-5 & 8:12, & 34-47.
(2) Self-righteousness - Zephaniah 1:8, Proverbs 30:12, Isaiah 65:5 ...'They will immediately take some of the Saviour's new cloth to patch their old garment with (for they cannot venture upon Christ alone), and so wear a garment of linen and woollen together Deuteronomy 32:11; and by this method the rent is made worse.'
(3) 'The next prop of the devil's kingdom is false confidence/false hope. Job:8:14 Satan influences the mind of the wretched sinner with an infernal persuasion and a firm confidence in things which are arrant lies - 2 Thessalonians 2:9-12'
(4) Carnal security, or false peace: as Christ tells us, "When the strong man armed keepeth the palace, his goods are in peace. But when a stronger than he shall come upon him and overcome him, he taketh from him all his armour herein he trusted, and divideth his spoils." Luke 11:21-22 & Jeremiah 8:10-11
(5) Pride is the highest state of majesty in Satan's Empire, hence novices must not be appointed in congregations of God's people - 1 Timothy 3:6. The scorner's chair is the highest bench in Satan's kingdom.
(6) Sin and death. "To keep up the government of these two is the chief of Satan's labour, whether it be in his subjects or by them... [but] both sin and death, which came by Satan, shall be in the everlasting destruction of himself and of all that die in his interest [at Christ's coming at the Day of Resurrection and Judgment.] (Ibid pp. 362-371)
This serves to show that the kingdom of Satan has never been divided, and rules over his billions of subjects throughout Earth's history, to this very day. Once his tactics are exposed, then we see it is not earthly governments or kingdoms that this is all about, but the spiritual, invisible rule of sin as the would-be-usurper, Satan, strives to wrest the rights of Christ, the King, from him. Well, he failed at Golgotha, when Christ triumphed over him, and now has to wait till God decrees the time to send him and all his subjects, devil or human, into perdition. But Satan's Empire itself, which is invisible, has never been divided. Ezekiel 30 speaks of earthly kingdoms, yes, but without grasping the spiritual dimension, it will all seem a bit peculiar to us. There is no discrepancy, just deeper depths to be plumbed. For those who don't do that, they may unwittingly be subjects of Satan's empire, unaware of all his tactics to keep them enslaved to sin and death.
https://www.williamhuntington.net/Works/

Up-voted. Solemn reminders of the awful state of the damned.

I think there are two parts to the answer. First, it helps to consider who Satan is and what he wants to achieve. He's a murderer (John 8:44), he comes to steal, kill and destroy (John 10:10). When earthly kingdoms go to war, they may be divided among themselves, but they may still be serving Satan's purposes. If people die without a further chance to repent, for him that's all well and good. Therefore we can't say that Satan is divided against himself. By contrast, if Satan was to cast out demons, he'd be taking a person he already has complete control over and setting him free, which is clearly acting against himself.
The second part of the answer is that, while Satan has temporary power on earth, he's still subject to God's authority. God still intervenes to direct human affairs (Proverbs 21:1, for example). He uses even war to serve His purposes, such as punishment for sin (2 Kings 19:25, as referenced by David's comment, or Ezekiel 30 which you yourself quoted). So when earthly events seem to go against Satan's purposes, he's still not divided against himself - he may have simply been overruled.
Note that this doesn't necessarily contradict Satan's power on earth. The king may be doing evil things for evil reasons, and accidentally serving God's purpose in the process - again, see Sennacherib.

This. If one ungodly nation conquerors another, Satan has not been "cast out" in the process; what's left is still an ungodly nation. Thus, ungodly nations warring is not "Satan cast[ing] out Satan", it is simply violence (which is itself ungodly).
